# Ошибка при использовании input()

Tags: python

Такой код:

```py
a = input("Введите два целых числа:")
b, c = map(int, input().split())
print ("Ответ", b+c)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python39/12.py", line 2, in <module>
    b, c = map(int, input().split())
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

Comment: Какую ошибку-то?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python39/12.py", line 2, in <module>
    b, c = map(int, input().split())
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
>>>

Comment: в заголовке вопроса должен быть заголовок вопроса. а не кусок непонятного кода.

Comment: для этого нужно ввести какие то числа?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка состоит в то, что пытаемся получить данные ещё раз, а вводим одно число:

```
b, c = map(int, input().split())
```

Надо так:

```
a = input("Введите два целых числа: ") 
b,c = map(int, a.split()) 
print ("Ответ", b+c)

Введите два целых числа:1 2
Ответ 3
```

Comment: спасибо)))))))))

Answer (score 1):

Код запустил, ошибок нету. Проблема в тому, что Вы команду input() вызваете 2 раза, тобишь код должен выглядеть вот так:

```
b, c = map(int, input("Введите 2 числа: ").split()) 
print ("Ответ", b+c)
```

Без присвоения переменной "а" абстрактного значения.